# Is there any way to retrieve the compiler-generated code from the .NET assembly in a readable form?

Tags: c#, .net, il, reflector, ildasm

For example, if some C# class in an assembly has a property `property`, compiler generates `set_property` and `get_property` methods, or if there is a lambda, compiler also generates helper class `c__DisplayClass` or something like it. I can see them when I disassemble the assembly using ILDasm, but ILDasm shows me the IL code, which is not very convenient for reading. On the other hand, if I use ILSpy or Reflector, they show me the code I've written, without classes and methods that have been generated by compiler. Is there any halfway method, which allows to see the compiler-generated classes and methods, but in a somewhat readable form, at least more readable than IL?

Comment: Well, use ILSpy or Reflector.  The job they do, converting the IL back to readable C# code, is *very* untrivial and not generally available in a library.

Comment: @HansPassant but what if I want to see, for example, just out of curiosity, how a particular lambda is implemented behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, my question appeared to be rather stupid, because ILSpy, JustDecompile and, I suspect, other decompilers too, have the option preventing the decompiling of lambdas.

Comment: Indeed.  On at least one of them, it's activated by choosing ".NET 2.0" code, while selecting a later version recognizes lambdas.